# divide a file into packets with python(PyCharm) and send it via BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ota

i need an example of a python script which split a file into packets and send them via BLE
(Firmware update OTA from a pc to a device)

Comment: What stops you from reading the full file and doing the splitting afterward using firmware_file[0:100] for the first 100 characters?